# Is there a bound for L_1 distance involving the integral probability metric?

Tags: probability-theory, integral-inequality

I'm wondering if there is a way to bound $$ \left\| \int f dP - \int f dQ \right\| $$ by the $L_1$ distance between $P$ and $Q$: $$\int \left\| dP - dQ \right\| $$.

So far, I've only been able to show that $L_1(P,Q)$ is bounded from below by the squared Hellinger distance between $P$ and $Q$, but I don't see how to relate $L_1$ with integral probability metric.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $f$? Is it supposed to be 1-Lipschitz (Wasserstein metric)?

Comment: I wasn't assuming Lipschitz continuity but is that necessary to bound the first distance? I know it's sufficient because of Kantorovich Rubinstein (?)...

Comment: I am basically asking what is your definition of integral probability metric. I assume you take the supremum of what you wrote over all $f$'s in some particular class of functions -- which class?

Comment: Only assumptions I was thinking about were that the functions were bounded in $[a,b]$.

Comment: It looks like at least one of us is confused about the definition. How do you define the *metric* you want over the space of probability distributions? As you wrote, it's unspecified. For two distributions $P,Q$, $d(P,Q)=?$

Comment: Oh I see -- yeah it's $\sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} \left\| \int f\, dP - \int f\, dQ \right\|$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the class of bounded functions taking values between $[a,b]$.